# MODIS Fire Product tile conversion to GeoTIFF problem

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, modis, gdal-translate

I downloaded a tile (selected tile in the picture) from

https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order/3/MOD14--6/2019-08-09/DB/Tile:H25V6

[image]

I used `gdalinfo` on the file. It's output is

```
Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
Files: MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  ANCILLARYINPUTPOINTER.1=MOD03.A2019221.0450.006.2019221110913.hdf
  ANCILLARYINPUTTYPE.1=Geolocation
  ASSOCIATEDINSTRUMENTSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  ASSOCIATEDPLATFORMSHORTNAME.1=Terra
  ASSOCIATEDSENSORSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAG.1=Suspect
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION.1=not being investigated
  ClearingRejectedPix=0
  CloudAdjacentFirePix=1
  CLOUDADJACENTFIREPIXELS=1
  CLOUDPIXELS=1103636
  CoastPix=35606
  CoastRejectedLandPix=0
  CoastRejectedWaterPix=0
  DAYNIGHTFLAG=Day
  DayPix=2748620
  DESCRREVISION=6.0
  EASTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=104.710721559695
  EQUATORCROSSINGDATE.1=2019-08-09
  EQUATORCROSSINGLONGITUDE.1=82.3289279388635
  EQUATORCROSSINGTIME.1=05:00:57.839182
  EXCLUSIONGRINGFLAG.1=N
  FirePix=7
  FIREPIXELS=7
  GlintPix=360630
  GLINTPIXELS=11
  GlintRejectedPix=11
  GRANULENUMBER=60
  GRINGPOINTLATITUDE.1=40.8453884481622, 36.9864128503041, 19.5369579507064, 22.6021317560853
  GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE.1=77.9618967354649, 104.724893737855, 98.2448894475871, 75.8292560777532
  GRINGPOINTSEQUENCENO.1=1, 2, 3, 4
  HotSurfRejectedPix=0
  identifier_product_doi=10.5067/MODIS/MOD14.006
  identifier_product_doi=10.5067/MODIS/MOD14.006
  identifier_product_doi_authority=http://dx.doi.org
  identifier_product_doi_authority=http://dx.doi.org
  INPUTPOINTER=MOD021KM.A2019221.0450.006.2019221131039.hdf, MOD03.A2019221.0450.006.2019221110913.hdf
  INSTRUMENTSCANSPROCESSED=203
  INTERNALCLOUDMASK=yes
  LandCloudPix=1040727
  LandFirePix=7
  LandPix=2633347
  LOCALGRANULEID=MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf
  LOCALVERSIONID=6.2.3
  LONGNAME=MODIS/Terra Thermal Anomalies/Fire 5-Min L2 Swath 1km
  MissingGeoPix=0
  MissingPix=50
  MissingRadPix=50
  MOD021KM input file=/MODAPSops8/archive/f7038/running/AM1M_C6_64_L1mc/164701912/MOD021KM.A2019221.0450.006.2019221131039.hdf
  MOD03 input file=/MODAPSops8/archive/f7038/running/AM1M_C6_64_L1mc/164701912/MOD03.A2019221.0450.006.2019221110913.hdf
  NightPix=0
  NOFIREPIXELS=1598312
  NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=40.8208843728029
  ORBITNUMBER.1=104469
  PARAMETERNAME.1=MODIS L2 Active Fire Detection
  PERCENTLAND=95
  PGEVERSION=6.0.13
  PROCESSINGCENTER=MODAPS
  PROCESSINGENVIRONMENT=Linux minion7038 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64
  PROCESSVERSION=6.2.3
  ProcessVersionNumber=6.2.3
  PRODUCTIONDATETIME=2019-08-09T13:17:04.000Z
  QAPERCENTGOODQUALITY=100
  QAPERCENTMISSINGDATA.1=0
  QAPERCENTNOTPRODUCEDCLOUD=40
  QAPERCENTNOTPRODUCEDOTHER=0
  QAPERCENTOTHERQUALITY=0
  RANGEBEGINNINGDATE=2019-08-09
  RANGEBEGINNINGTIME=04:50:00.000000
  RANGEENDINGDATE=2019-08-09
  RANGEENDINGTIME=04:55:00.000000
  REPROCESSINGACTUAL=processed once
  REPROCESSINGPLANNED=further update is anticipated
  Satellite=Terra
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAG.1=Not Investigated
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION.1=See http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/qaFlagPage.cgi?sat=terra for the product Science Quality status.
  SHORTNAME=MOD14
  SOUTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=19.5959528606655
  SPSOPARAMETERS=2663, 2664, 2665, 2666, 2711
  SystemID=Linux minion7038 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64
  UnknownLandPix=4
  UNKNOWNPIXELS=46615
  UnknownWaterPix=46611
  VERSIONID=6
  WaterAdjacentFirePix=1
  WATERADJACENTFIREPIXELS=1
  WaterCloudPix=62909
  WaterFirePix=0
  WaterPix=79617
  WATERPIXELS=79617
  WESTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=75.8540712874917
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":0
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[2030x1354] fire mask (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":1
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[2030x1354] algorithm QA (32-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":29
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[7348x8] CMG_day (16-bit unsigned integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

I then used the command

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs "EPSG:4326" HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":0 out.tif`

On visualising it on QGIS it appears like this,

[image]

How can I correctly be able to generate to GeoTIFF so it appears as the tile is seen in the first picture?
Also,  as I am very new to exploring such data, what is the explanation for the previous behavior?

I have tried this approach creating a VRT and then creating a GeoTIFF
[Unable to warp HDF5 files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/unable-to-warp-hdf5-files)

**Edit - 1**
`gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -gcp 0 0 77.96189673546 40.8208843728029 -gcp 1354 0 104.724893737855 40.8208843728029 -gcp 1354 2030 98.2448894475871 19.5959528606655 -gcp 0 2030 75.8540712874917 19.5959528606655 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":0 out_gcp.tif`

Using this (using the GRingPoint latitude/longitude and the bounding coordinates,

[image]

But this is still not correctly projected.

Comment: Your data gets placed so that the top-left corner is at coordinates 0,0. GDAL HDF4 driver supports reading georeference from some kind of HDF4 files https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html but I am  not sure if this product belongs to the supported ones.

Comment: Do you know of anyway in which i can get the corner coordinates (lat/long)? Currently I only know the bounds in the four directions.
https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf5.html This page shows information about the crs plus GCP mapping. But in the product I mentioned, I see no such information.

Comment: HDF4 and HDF5 are not the same. I found GRINGPOINTLATITUDE and -LONGITUDE lists from your gdalinfo and tried to use them as ground control points but the two eastern points do not fit with the tile bounds so it was just waste of time.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128040/warping-images-with-unknown-projection

I checked this and wanted to add gcp like it was mentioned here but could not find the required points.

Comment: What I did was to check the size of the image and take the four points from the GRINGPOINT metadata. The command that I wrote was `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -gcp 0 0 77.9618967354649 40.8453884481622 -gcp 1354 0 104.724893737855 36.9864128503041 -gcp 1354 2030 98.2448894475871 19.5369579507064 -gcp 0 2030 75.8292560777532 22.6021317560853 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":0 out_gcp.tif` but the result was not good but all too wide. Georeferencing image with QGIS georeferencer could be one option. Lakes and the Brahmaputra river show fine on the image.

Comment: I followed your approach and used the 'NORTH/EAST/WEST/SOUTH' BOUNDING COORDINATES `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:4326 -gcp 0 0 77.96189673546 40.8208843728029 -gcp 1354 0 104.724893737855 40.8208843728029 -gcp 1354 2030 98.2448894475871 19.5959528606655 -gcp 0 2030 75.8540712874917 19.5959528606655 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD14.A2019221.0450.006.2019221091704.hdf":0 out_gcp.tif`. But it still does not look like the  original raster when projected in QGIS.

Comment: That's what I said. In addition that product is probably not a regular grid but observations are recorded along a sinusoidal swath and thus it is not possible to georeference the image well by having control points just at the corners. Use the georeferencer, measure quite many control points and use the thin spline method.

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html
You mean something like this?

Is there so other option? Because i assumed it is a popular product and lot of people in this field would be using it somehow. Also, if you had an .xml file along with this, would it help?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to download the fire data from the 'FIRMS Archive Download' page[1]. This data is already converted to a WGS84 projection instead of the raw sinusoidal format [2].

1. https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/download/
2. https://earthdata.nasa.gov/faq/firms-faq#ed-nrt-standard

Answer (score 0):

I think your data maybe swath data that needs reprojection (from the `gdalinfo` output: `LONGNAME=MODIS/Terra Thermal Anomalies/Fire 5-Min L2 Swath 1km`). Generally, you'd need the MOD03 product to do a full projection (but since this is direct broadcast, it may be different?). Other easier options are to use  the data from FIRMS as they mention above, or use one of the projected products, e.g., [MOD14A1](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod14a1v006/) and/or [MYD14A1](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/myd14a1v006/) for daily gridded (there's also a weekly gridded product too, I think).

Answer (score -1):

There's a [QGIS tutorial "Wildfire Monitoring Using The Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin"](https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2017/01/wildfire-monitoring.html) that seems to cover downloading as well as the necessary analysis steps. I haven't tried it myself but it should be a starting point.